# Add show("slow") while adding new field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id)).show("slow");
}
```

I've added `.show("slow")` so that the new field will be shown slowly, but it ain't working. I have tried moving it around the same line, but nothing works.

Where have I gone wrong in this? Thanks.

Comment: So what is the actual problem, is it not showing _slowly_ or is it not showing _at all_?

Comment: It shows. Just the animation `.show("slow")` is not applied.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't show slowly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.before() returns $(link).parent(), not the inserted element.
Depending if content contains a HTML string with exactly one top level element, this might do:

```
$(link).
  parent().
  before(content.replace(regexp, new_id)).
  prev(). // get $(link).parent()'s previous sibling aka newly inserted element
  hide().
  show("slow");`
```